# Add graphviz plot inside matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx, graphviz

I am visualizing various networks with `networkx`. Take a look at simple example

```py
    graph = nx.DiGraph()
    graph.add_edge("a", "b")
    graph.add_edge("a", "a")
    nx.draw(graph)
    plt.show()
```

Unfortunately, `networkx` plotting does not render self loops. I am aware of other feature rich packages like `GraphViz` and its implementation `pygraphviz`. However, such packages do not allow me to customize my plots (like subplots, annotations etc). I can do all of these with `networkx` as it can plot with `matplotlib` Axes. Which is very convenient for programmatic manipulations and heavy customizations. Is there way to get network plotting of `GraphViz` to `matplotlib`?

I can always embed PNG created by `GraphViz` into `matplotlib` plots using `imshow`. However, its results are horrible with little customization control.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn’t seem like this exists yet. If you want to implement it yourself, there are a few options. If you want to leave the layout to Graphviz and just hand shapes and positions to Matplotlib, two options remain to get the data necessary for rendering:

1. You use the binaries (like `dot`) with the [`-Tjson` option](https://www.graphviz.org/docs/outputs/json/), which seems to emit all necessary data for drawing, but I didn’t find documentation for what e.g. the `op`s are.
2. You [Use Graphviz as a Library](https://www.graphviz.org/pdf/libguide.pdf). Section 2.3 (Rendering the graph) describes how to access the data.

You then feed this data into the `Axes`’ [`Artist` (tutorial)](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/artists.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-intermediate-artists-py). Matplotlib also has a [tutorial for how to draw paths](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/advanced/path_tutorial.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-advanced-path-tutorial-py).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you say networkx does not render self-loops. Isn't this what you are looking for?

```
import networkx as nx
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

graph = nx.DiGraph()
graph.add_edges_from([("a", "b"), ("a", "a"), ("b", "b"), ("c", "b"), ("c", "c")])
nx.draw(graph, with_labels=True)
plt.show()
```

[image]